# Remove/Whitelist all bindings in Clojure

Tags: binding, clojure, eval

In my little game project, i want player to manipulate some in-game stuff writing some Clojure scripts right in the game. So, i downloaded Clojure lib and used this code:

```kotlin
private val eval = Clojure.`var`("clojure.core", "eval")

fun eval(code: String): Any? =
    try {
        eval.invoke(Clojure.read("(do $code)"))
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
```

but the thing is, by doing so player can manipulate the whole program, as it is runs in same environment, as the game code. The simplest example is `(System/exit 0)`.

My question is - how to remove all Clojure bindings from my scripting context except some basic predefined stuff, like math operators, collection magic and so on?

Also, i can put my own bindings(for wiring these scripts to actual game logic) with `eval.invoke("(def do-magic [x] (println "magic"))")`, but is there a more consistent way to do this?

upd:
I need to do *really* *simple* stuff like math and jumping around with simple functions. Maybe a bit of collection magic. So i need to block *everything* except this stuff, so any unsafe code just cant exist at all.

Comment: what about using cljs instead of clj, and running player code via embedded js eval (eg. rhino)? this will likely be much simpler to sandbox

Comment: Oh, that is the proper word to google this kind of stuff! `sandbox`! Thank you very much, found a lot of articles about it, finally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This technique is called `sandbox` and simply googling "clojure sandbox" finally led me to the articles about this topic.

UPD:
I've needed to *whitelist* stuff, not *blacklist* as it was used on the internet.
Spent whole day, but finally got this to work properly

```kotlin
private val eval = Clojure.`var`("clojure.core", "eval")

val whitelist = listOf("+", "-", "*", "/", "=") // example

init {
    val wh = whitelist.joinToString(" ", "[", "]") { "\"$it\"" }
    eval("""
        (let [wh (vec (map symbol $wh))]
          (doseq [n (all-ns) :let [n (ns-name n)]]
            (if (= (str n) "clojure.core")
              (doseq [[k _] (ns-map n) :when (not (some (fn [x] (= x k)) wh))]
                (ns-unmap n k))
              (remove-ns n))))
    """)
}

fun eval(code: String): Any? =
    try {
        eval.invoke(Clojure.read("(do $code)"))
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
```